# How can I undo "always allow" in keychain item

Tags: macos, keychain

By mistake, I clicked on "always allow" on a file in my keychain on the Mac. How do I undo this and restrict access? I tried to correct it by clicking on Access Control. There I selected "confirm before allowing access" but it didn't work. I can still see the password for that file without entering a password.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to clear out any white listed programs and then reset the default behavior from Keychain Access.

[image]

- First select Fantastical (or any apps that are cleared) and then press the -
- Second, choose Confirm and Ask as needed.
- Third, select Attributes and make sure the changes are saved (you should probably have to authenticate as well at this step)
- Go back to Access Control to verify the settings have been saved properly

If this doesn't work, you might need to repair that keychain containing that item, also using Keychain Access menu to open the Keychain First Aid tool.

Comment: I don't know if this is still valid or if you might be able to add how exactly to get to this screen.  Whenever I open "Keychain Access" from Spotlight Search, I get a screen for dealing with system certificates.  I'm not sure how to get to the exact image that you are showing in your answer.  Could you add how to find that "Access Control" window?

Comment: @zero298 right click on a credential row to get dropdown, then click "Get Info"