# How to Undo Deny Access on Keychain

Tags: macos, permission, keychain

When accessing a secure note on my login keychain (Using the Keychain Access app) I accidentally selected "Deny" on the prompt.

Now I have no access to this keychain anymore. All of my applications that were previously able to access the keychain are denied as well. All items in the keychain have this issue.

The "Access Control" on the individual items in the keychain does not indicated that access is restricted.

Other keychains do not have this problem.

The error that I get is "Access to this item is restricted (-67808)"

How do I undo this action?

Comment: This previous article might be useful - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25321/keychain-says-access-to-this-item-is-restricted-after-upgrading-to-lion

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. I tried that one but no luck. I don't think there is an issue with the keychain itself. Its not corrupt and there are no permission issues on the file.

Comment: Ive called apple support regarding this and it has been escalated to their engineering team. I will update this once they come back with a solution

Comment: The solution is to edit the keychain items. See my answer to the question http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/116211/5472

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue after accidentally hitting deny.
After repairing keychain, repairing permissions and touching the keychain file. I finally locked the keychain then unlocked it. That seemed to do the trick.